# Color change of a button in code not reflecting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to change a color of a button in code as below

```
 btn_no5.setTextColor(0x8E35EF);
```

the above change is not reflecting(purple color),  the text is disappearing after execution of above piece of code. But if i use the color in xml its reflecting. So how to change this through java ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color you are using is fully transparent. Use 0xFF8E35EF instead. The first byte is the alpha (transparency) channel.

Answer (score 1):

use like this,

```
btn_no5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8E35EF"));
```

Comment: Ya this is working,but can u say what happens with Color.parseColor("#8E35EF") ?

Comment: hi this Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int.The supported formats are #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'. The 'AA' represents transparency.